# Video control validations in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating a survey which should consist of video in it. I need to validate the video should completely watched by respondent.

Comment: make sure it's been the video's duration since you served it.

Comment: `if( (peformance.now() / 1000) < video.duration ){ ... }`

Comment: video duration can be kept in terms seconds like suppose if it is for 1.30 seconds we need to write as 90 seconds?

Comment: @dandavis, this doesn't take into account the loading of the page and of the video. Either you add a listener on video's `timeupdate`, incrementing a variable and check if the amount reached approximately corresponds to video's duration*30 or alternatively use the same event and check whether the currentTime of the last call was more or less than 1/30 s, and if no problem (if user didn't clicked the timeline), attach the callback to `onended`. Or, for such a short movie, you can just attach the callback on `onended`, there is low chances that the user skipped a large amount of the video.

Comment: i'm presuming that the loading of the page and video takes about the same amount of time that the user will take to click next after the video is done playing. it's a minimum amount of time that's its possible to have watched the video, and is very simple to impliment. you can note performance.now()'s value at the time the video starts playing if the couple seconds of precision is important.